# Nuxt 3 SSR with node-server as preset

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nitro

I am building a nuxt 3 app with node-server as preset. This will be hosted on a server running node js. Npm run build produces `.nuxt` and `.output` correctly and I can see that .output has a node_modules in it.

The issue I have is that the .nuxt folder doesn't contain node_modules and to get it working I had to upload my local node_modules on the root folder of the server.
Is there a way to get nuxt to build the output with node_modules for both .nuxt and .output?